# How can I check if the array of objects have duplicate property values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

I need some help with iterating through array, I keep getting stuck or reinventing the wheel.

```
values = [
    { name: 'someName1' },
    { name: 'someName2' },
    { name: 'someName1' },
    { name: 'someName1' }
]
```

How could I check if there are two (or more) same name value in array? I do not need a counter, just setting some variable if array values are not unique. Have in mind that array length is dynamic, also array values.

Comment: @AmiTavory There's at least one clear difference -- that question looks at an array of primitives (`arr = [9, 9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];`), and this looks at deduping based on the properties of objects. Semantic, perhaps, but the two highest voted answers there don't exactly address this case. `/giphy the more you know` (I realize that won't do anything)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use [array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var values = [
    { name: 'someName1' },
    { name: 'someName2' },
    { name: 'someName4' },
    { name: 'someName2' }
];

var valueArr = values.map(function(item){ return item.name });
var isDuplicate = valueArr.some(function(item, idx){ 
    return valueArr.indexOf(item) != idx 
});
console.log(isDuplicate);
```

Comment: `indexOf` will give very bad performance, if the array is big.

Comment: I'll replace the return part by: return valueArr.indexOf(item, idx + 1) !== -1

Comment: Another option can be `new Set(arr).size !== arr.length` to check if the array has duplicates.

Comment: @JoelFernando - The answer was written 6 years ago and below, someone added an ES6 answer that works with a `Set`. Your answer will work with an array of primitives. The question here is about an array of objects where the inner property is the one we don't want to duplicate.

Answer (score 91):

**ECMA Script 6 Version**

If you are in an environment which supports ECMA Script 6's [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size), then you can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and a `Set` object, like this

```
let seen = new Set();
var hasDuplicates = values.some(function(currentObject) {
    return seen.size === seen.add(currentObject.name).size;
});
```

Here, we insert each and every object's `name` into the `Set` and we check if the `size` before and after adding are the same. This works because `Set.size` returns a number based on unique data (set only adds entries if the data is unique). If/when you have duplicate names, the size won't increase (because the data won't be unique) which means that we would have already seen the current name and it will return true.

---

**ECMA Script 5 Version**

If you don't have `Set` support, then you can use a normal JavaScript object itself, like this

```
var seen = {};
var hasDuplicates = values.some(function(currentObject) {

    if (seen.hasOwnProperty(currentObject.name)) {
        // Current name is already seen
        return true;
    }

    // Current name is being seen for the first time
    return (seen[currentObject.name] = false);
});
```

The same can be written succinctly, like this

```
var seen = {};
var hasDuplicates = values.some(function (currentObject) {
    return seen.hasOwnProperty(currentObject.name)
        || (seen[currentObject.name] = false);
});
```

---

**Note:** In both the cases, we use `Array.prototype.some` because it will short-circuit. The moment it gets a truthy value from the function, it will return `true` immediately, it will not process rest of the elements.

Comment: Interesting approach, using `hasOwnProperty`. I saw in a few other answers you commented that `indexOf` will have poor performance in large arrays. Is the above ES5 way you suggested more performance friendly in general for larger objects?

Comment: @JoshBeam `indexOf` will have to iterate the array to find out if the element is there or not, but anything which uses hashing will be much faster. So, both the ES5 and ES6 ways will be much faster if the array is quite big.

Comment: How can I make sure, it will process the rest of the elements?

Comment: @AnnaSmother If you want to process all the elements, then use `forEach` and write the logic yourself.

Comment: `var hasDuplicates`? the questions asks how to remove duplicates in an array of objects by property name. Your method seems to give me all the duplicates.

Comment: @chovy The question is: "How could I check if there are two (or more) same name value in array? I do not need a counter, just setting some variable if array values are not unique." which has nothing to do with removing the duplicates.

I think this is the best answer here!

Comment: also for the ECMA 6 answer, for comparisons with more attributes just add more logical comparisons inside the function chained with the && operator (like adding currentObject.id and currentObject.otherValue)

Comment: To get array of duplicates use filter instead of some: 
      let seen = new Set();
      const duplicates = records.filter(
        (record: { name: string }) =>
          seen.size === seen.add(name.contractRefNumber).size
      );

Answer (score 86):

In TS and ES6 you can create a new Set with the property to be unique and compare it's size to the original array.

```js
const values = [
  { name: 'someName1' },
  { name: 'someName2' },
  { name: 'someName3' },
  { name: 'someName1' }
]

const uniqueValues = new Set(values.map(v => v.name));

if (uniqueValues.size < values.length) {
  console.log('duplicates found')
}
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer

Comment: If you plan to turn this into a helper function, then beware that anytime you use a non-existent property to do your check, or the object is missing that property, you can end up with a false positive. For example, if last two objects in `values` were missing `name` property, then `values.map((v) => v.name)` would return `['someName1', 'someName2', undefined, undefined]` and `hasDuplicates()` would return `true` even though it's not really what you were after. Hence, this works best when used in TS with a proper interface.

Answer (score 9):

> To know if simple array has duplicates we can compare *first* and *last* indexes of the  same value:

The function:

```
var hasDupsSimple = function(array) {

    return array.some(function(value) {                            // .some will break as soon as duplicate found (no need to itterate over all array)
       return array.indexOf(value) !== array.lastIndexOf(value);   // comparing first and last indexes of the same value
    })
}
```

Tests:

```
hasDupsSimple([1,2,3,4,2,7])
// => true

hasDupsSimple([1,2,3,4,8,7])
// => false

hasDupsSimple([1,"hello",3,"bye","hello",7])
// => true
```

> For an array of objects we need to convert the objects values to a simple array first:

Converting array of objects to the simple array with `map`:

```
var hasDupsObjects = function(array) {

  return array.map(function(value) {
    return value.suit + value.rank

  }).some(function(value, index, array) { 
       return array.indexOf(value) !== array.lastIndexOf(value);  
     })
}
```

Tests:

```
var cardHand = [
  { "suit":"spades", "rank":"ten" },
  { "suit":"diamonds", "rank":"ace" },
  { "suit":"hearts", "rank":"ten" },
  { "suit":"clubs", "rank":"two" },
  { "suit":"spades", "rank":"three" },
]

hasDupsObjects(cardHand);
// => false
```

---

```
var cardHand2 = [
  { "suit":"spades", "rank":"ten" },
  { "suit":"diamonds", "rank":"ace" },
  { "suit":"hearts", "rank":"ten" },
  { "suit":"clubs", "rank":"two" },
  { "suit":"spades", "rank":"ten" },
]

hasDupsObjects(cardHand2);
// => true
```

Comment: how to find the index also latest duplication value

Comment: @SystemsRebooter, Thanks !! exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

```js
const values = [
    { name: 'someName1' },
    { name: 'someName2' },
    { name: 'someName4' },
    { name: 'someName4' }
];

const foundDuplicateName = values.find((nnn, index) =>{
   return values.find((x, ind)=> x.name === nnn.name && index !== ind )
    })
    
    console.log(foundDuplicateName)
```

Found the first one duplicate name

```
const values = [
    { name: 'someName1' },
    { name: 'someName2' },
    { name: 'someName4' },
    { name: 'someName4' }
];

const foundDuplicateName = values.find((nnn, index) =>{
   return values.find((x, ind)=> x.name === nnn.name && index !== ind )
    })
```

Answer (score 7):

if you are looking for a boolean, the quickest way would be

```js
var values = [
    { name: 'someName1' },
    { name: 'someName2' },
    { name: 'someName1' },
    { name: 'someName1' }
]

// solution
var hasDuplicate = false;
values.map(v => v.name).sort().sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === b) hasDuplicate = true
})
console.log('hasDuplicate', hasDuplicate)
```

Comment: It may be the quickest way to write but definitely not the quickest way in terms of execution speed considering you are sorting twice over and above Array.map()

Answer (score 5):

You just need one line of code.

```
var values = [
        { name: 'someName1' },
        { name: 'someName2' },
        { name: 'someName4' },
        { name: 'someName2' }
     ];
        let hasDuplicates = values.map(v => v.name).length > new Set(values.map(v => v.name)).size ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try an simple loop:

```js
var repeat = [], tmp, i = 0;

while(i < values.length){
  repeat.indexOf(tmp = values[i++].name) > -1 ? values.pop(i--) : repeat.push(tmp)
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wZVanG/1sea3x0e/)**

Comment: This just ends up with a de-duped array of them.

Answer (score 2):

**With Underscore.js** A few ways with Underscore can be done. Here is one of them. Checking if the array is already unique.

```
function isNameUnique(values){
    return _.uniq(values, function(v){ return v.name }).length == values.length
}
```

**With vanilla JavaScript** 
By checking if there is no recurring names in the array.

```
function isNameUnique(values){
    var names = values.map(function(v){ return v.name });
    return !names.some(function(v){ 
        return names.filter(function(w){ return w==v }).length>1 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//checking duplicate elements in an array
var arr=[1,3,4,6,8,9,1,3,4,7];
var hp=new Map();
console.log(arr.sort());
var freq=0;
for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
// console.log(arr[i-1]+" "+arr[i]);
if(arr[i]==arr[i-1]){
freq++;

}
else{
hp.set(arr[i-1],freq+1);
freq=0;
}
}
console.log(hp);
```

Comment: copy and paste run with node scriptname.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return just the name, and then use this [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) trick to check if it exists at least twice:

```
var areAnyDuplicates = false;

values.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.name;
}).forEach(function (element, index, arr) {
    if (arr.indexOf(element) !== index) {
        areAnyDuplicates = true;
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qo4xwv5s/)

Comment: `indexOf` will give very bad performance, if the array is big.

Answer (score 1):

> It is quite interesting to work with arrays

> You can use **new** **Set()** **method** to find **duplicate** values!

- let's assume you have an array of objects like this...

---

```
 let myArray = [
            { id: 0, name: "Jhon" },
            { id: 1, name: "sara" },
            { id: 2, name: "pop" },
            { id: 3, name: "sara" }
        ]

const findUnique = new Set(myArray.map(x => {
    return x.name
}))

if(findUnique.size < myArray.length){
    console.log("duplicates found!")
}else{
    console.log("Done!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will output an array of objects that have duplicates based on the name property:

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Jane' },
  { id: 3, name: 'John' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Jane' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Adam' }
];

const duplicates = array.reduce((acc, obj, index) => {
  const duplicates = array.filter((item, i) =>
    i !== index && item.name === obj.name
  );

  if (duplicates.length > 0 && !acc.some(dup => dup.name === obj.name)) {
    return acc.concat([obj]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding updated es6 function to check for unique and duplicate values in array. This function is modular and can be reused throughout the code base. Thanks to all the post above.

```js
/* checks for unique keynames in array */
const checkForUnique = (arrToCheck, keyName) => {
    /* make set to remove duplicates and compare to  */
  const uniqueValues = [...new Set(arrToCheck.map(v => v[keyName]))];
  if(arrToCheck.length !== uniqueValues.length){
    console.log('NOT UNIQUE')
    return false
  }
  return true
}


let arr = [{name:'joshua'},{name:'tony'},{name:'joshua'}]

/* call function with arr and key to check for  */
let isUnique = checkForUnique(arr,'name')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkDuplicate(arr, item) {
   const uniqueValues = new Set(arr.map((v) => v[item]));
   return uniqueValues.size < arr.length;
},

console.log(this.checkDuplicate(this.dutyExemptionBase, 'CI_ExemptionType')); // true || false
```

Answer (score 0):

No `Set`, `map`, or extra variable required. Just use `some` twice. The first time it finds a duplicate, it returns `true`. No need to continue looping over the entire array.

```
const isDuplicate = values.some((e, i) => values.some((f, j) => i === j ? false : e.name === f.name))
```

Modify the last equality check `e.name === f.name` to match the property you want to check against.

Answer (score -1):

```
const duplicateValues = [{ name: "abc" }, { name: "bcv" }, { name: "abc" }];
const isContainDuplicate = (params) => {
  const removedDuplicate = new Set(params.map((el) => el.name));
  return params.length !== removedDuplicate.size;
};
const isDuplicate = isContainDuplicate(duplicateValues);
console.log("isDuplicate");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit your post and add additional supporting information as the comment above says. This will actually help people who come across this problem, the extra 2 minutes you spend will save these people over 20 minutes.