# How to delete duplicate values of objects inside array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I found several references about how to delete duplicate values in object like [this](https://reactgo.com/removeduplicateobjects/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750429/find-duplicate-values-inside-array-of-objects), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values)... In all these examples (and in others that I've found) are for simple objects, but my case is more "complex".

I have an array where each index has your values and an object inside. I create a simple example for explanation:

```
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Kyle",
    "item": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "name3"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2"
      }
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "name3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Liza",
    "item": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "item": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "name4"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "name4"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Melissa",
    "item": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How you can see, inside my `item` objects I've duplicate values... I would like to remove this duplicate values inside my objects.

One way to do this (which I thought) was do it making a copy of my list and using a `forEach`/`map`/`filter` but I don't know how to do it.

I tried this, but not works:

```
let dataCopy = data;

dataCopy.forEach(dataItem => {
  listPrev.forEach(dataPrev => {

    //??

    //and or...
    if(dataPrev.item.id == dataItem.item.id){          
      //??

    }
  })
})
```

I'm trying to get this kind of return:

```
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Kyle",
    "item": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "name3"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Liza",
    "item": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1"
      }
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "item": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "name4"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Melissa",
    "item": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How I can do it?
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `forEach` and `filter` will do:

```
data.forEach(d => {
    d.item = d.item.filter((item, index, self) => {
        return index === self.findIndex(z => z.id == item.id)
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your help! A doubt: I readed in the `filter` documentation that the third argument is equivalent to` this`. It's like a refer the own value filtered, right?

Comment: Yes, the third argument refers to the array being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array with `Array.map()`, and apply an array unique function to each `item` array:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Kyle","item":[{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"},{"id":3,"name":"name3"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"},{"id":3,"name":"name3"}]},{"name":"Liza","item":[{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}]},{"name":"John","item":[{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":4,"name":"name4"},{"id":4,"name":"name4"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}]},{"name":"Melissa","item":[{"id":2,"name":"name2"}]}];

const uniqueById = arr => Object.values(arr.reduce((r, o) => ({
  [o.id]: o,
  ...r
}), {}));

const result = data.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  item: uniqueById(o.item)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a utility function then map the collection like follow:

```
var dedupeBy = (arr, by) =>
  Object.values(arr.reduce((a, item) => ({ ...a, [item[by]]: item }), {}));
data.map((person) => ({ ...person, item: dedupeBy(person.item, 'name') }));
```