# How to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array of objects, and output only unique values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I'm learning JS. Supposing I have the below array of objects:

```
var family = [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Matt"
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    age: 85
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Carl",
    age: 40
  }
];
```

Notice that *Nancy* is showing up twice (changing only the age). Supposing I want to output only unique names. How do I output the above array of objects, without duplicates? ES6 answers *more than welcome.*

Related (couldn't find a good way for usage on objects):

- [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)
- [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

**EDIT** Here's what I tried. It works well with strings but I can't figure how to make it work with objects:

```
family.reduce((a, b) => {
  if (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ) {
    a.push(b);
  }
  return a;
},[]);
```

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Actually I tried most of answers from both related questions I mentioned.

Comment: can someone explain why those downvotes? Should I copy/paste any code that doesn't work here just to say I tried?

Comment: its because this isnt actually too hard, but require a little bit more research, google this: get unique objects array javascript

Comment: @RicoLetterman I edited my answer to address your edit, and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if the array of objects have duplicate property values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in combination with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...` in a single line.

Map returns an array with all names, which are going into the set initializer and then all values of the set are returned in an array.

```js
var family = [{ name: "Mike", age: 10 }, { name: "Matt", age: 13 }, { name: "Nancy", age: 15 }, { name: "Adam", age: 22 }, { name: "Jenny", age: 85 }, { name: "Nancy", age: 2 }, { name: "Carl", age: 40 }],
    unique = [...new Set(family.map(a => a.name))];

console.log(unique);
```

For filtering and return only unique names, you can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
var family = [{ name: "Mike", age: 10 }, { name: "Matt", age: 13 }, { name: "Nancy", age: 15 }, { name: "Adam", age: 22 }, { name: "Jenny", age: 85 }, { name: "Nancy", age: 2 }, { name: "Carl", age: 40 }],
    unique = family.filter((set => f => !set.has(f.name) && set.add(f.name))(new Set));

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Is there a way to output my array of objects instead of this flat array?

Comment: what about your question *I want to output only unique names.*? if not, which one would you like to get the first object, or the last?

Comment: Very well done.  I like the two options you thoroughly explained.

Comment: hi @Nina Scholz it's working fine but not work i IE11  give anyother solution

Comment: @jose, this question is marked ES6, and IE11 does not support it. you could use a hash table instead with an object and collect all names there.

Comment: any relavant example @Nina Scholz

Comment: @jose, you could use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482541/delete-duplicate-elements-from-array-in-javascript/40482611#40482611

Answer (score 15):

## The Solution

Store occurrences of `name` external to the loop in an object, and filter if there's been a previous occurrence.

https://jsfiddle.net/nputptbb/2/

```
var occurrences = {}

var filteredFamily = family.filter(function(x) {
  if (occurrences[x.name]) {
    return false;
  }
  occurrences[x.name] = true;
  return true;
})
```

you can also generalize this solution to a function

```
function filterByProperty(array, propertyName) {
  var occurrences = {}

  return array.filter(function(x) {
    var property = x[propertyName]
    if (occurrences[property]) {
      return false;
    }
    occurrences[property]] = true;
    return true;
  })
}
```

and use it like

```
var filteredFamily = filterByProperty(family, 'name')
```

## Explanation

Don't compare objects using `indexOf`, which only uses the `===` operator between objects. The reason why your current answer doesn't work is because `===` in JS does not compare the objects deeply, but instead compares the references. What I mean by that you can see in the following code:

```
var a = { x: 1 }
var b = { x: 1 }

console.log(a === b) // false
console.log(a === a) // true
```

Equality will tell you if you found the **same exact** object, but not if you found an object with the same contents.

In this case, you can compare your object on `name` since it should be a unique key. So `obj.name === obj.name` instead of `obj === obj`. Moreover another problem with your code that affects its runtime and not its function is that you use an `indexOf` inside of your `reduce`. `indexOf` is `O(n)`, which makes the complexity of your algorithm `O(n^2)`. Thus, it's better to use an object, which has `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: its probably because your fiddle write to the console...was running the fiddle, looking at o/p, and wondering anything worked...not really bothering to check the code first (and see its writing to console)

Comment: I really appreciate this answer -- it's cross-browser, performant, and easy-to-read.

Comment: So if theres a duplicate of the names, but you want the ages all stored in an age array. So the name nacey and age 2 is gone but what if you could add the age 2 to the object nacey that's left over. And you could have the nacey object age [15, 2]

Answer (score 5):

This will work fine.

```js
const result = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3].reduce((x, y) => x.includes(y) ? x : [...x, y], []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the `X` do and the `[spreadd x : y ] `? and the last empty array also `[ ]` ?

Answer (score 3):

With the code you mentioned, you can try:

```
family.filter((item, index, array) => {
  return array.map((mapItem) => mapItem['name']).indexOf(item['name']) === index
})
```

Or you can have a generic function to make it work for other array of objects as well:

```
function printUniqueResults (arrayOfObj, key) {
  return arrayOfObj.filter((item, index, array) => {
    return array.map((mapItem) => mapItem[key]).indexOf(item[key]) === index
  })
}
```

and then just use `printUniqueResults(family, 'name')`

**[(FIDDLE)](https://jsfiddle.net/wqtduawa/)**

Answer (score 3):

I just thought of 2 simple ways for Lodash users

**Given this array:**

```
let family = [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Matt",
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    age: 85
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Carl",
    age: 40
  }
]
```

**1. Find duplicates:**

```
let duplicatesArr = _.difference(family, _.uniqBy(family, 'name'), 'name')

// duplicatesArr:
// [{ 
//   name: "Nancy", 
//   age: 2 
// }]
```

**2 Find if there are duplicates, for validation purpose:**

```
let uniqArr = _.uniqBy(family, 'name')

if (uniqArr.length === family.length) {
    // No duplicates
}

if (uniqArr.length !== family.length) {
    // Has duplicates
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since most of the answers won't have a good performance, i thought i share my take on this:

```
const arrayWithDuplicateData = [{ id: 5, name: 'Facebook'}, { id: 3, name: 'Twitter' }, { id: 5, name: 'Facebook' }];


const uniqueObj = {};

arrayWithDuplicateData.forEach(i => {
  uniqueObj[i.id] = i;
});

const arrayWithoutDuplicates = Object.values(uniqueObj);
```

We're leveraging the fact that keys are unique within objects. That means the last duplication item inside the first array,  will win over its predecessors. If we'd want to change that, we could flip the array before iterating over it.

Also we're not bound to use only one property of our object for identifying duplications.

```
const arrayWithDuplicateData = [{ id: 5, name: 'Facebook'}, { id: 3, name: 'Twitter' }, { id: 5, name: 'Facebook' }];


const uniqueObj = {};

arrayWithDuplicateData.forEach(item => {
  uniqueObj[`${item.id}_${item.name}`] = item;
});

const arrayWithoutDuplicates = Object.values(uniqueObj);
```

Or we could simply add a check, if the uniqueObj already holds a key and if yes, not overwrite it.

Overall this way is not very costly in terms of performance and served me well so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably set up some kind of object. Since you've said ECMAScript 6, you have access to `Set`, but since you want to compare values on your objects, it will take a little more work than that.

An example might look something like this (removed namespace pattern for clarity):

```
var setOfValues = new Set();
var items = [];

function add(item, valueGetter) {
   var value = valueGetter(item);
   if (setOfValues.has(value))
      return;

   setOfValues.add(value);
   items.push(item);
}

function addMany(items, valueGetter) {
   items.forEach(item => add(item, valueGetter));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var family = [
...
];

addMany(family, item => item.name);

// items will now contain the unique items
```

Explanation: you need to pull a value from each object as it's added and decide if it has already been added yet, based on the value you get. It requires a  value getter, which is a function that given an item, returns a value (`item => item.name`). Then, you only add items whose values haven't already been seen.

---

A class implementation:

```
// Prevents duplicate objects from being added

class ObjectSet {
  constructor(key) {
    this.key = key;
    this.items = [];
    this.set = new Set();
  }

  add(item) {
    if (this.set.has(item[this.key])) return;
    this.set.add(item[this.key]);
    this.items.push(item);
  }

  addMany(items) {
    items.forEach(item => this.add(item));
  }
}

var mySet = new ObjectSet('name');
mySet.addMany(family);
console.log(mySet.items);
```

Comment: This is so unnecessarily, overly complex

Comment: @AR7 complex? I wrote it in like 5 minutes. It just looks ugly because that's how encapsulation works in javascript.

Comment: @AR7 I've remove the namespace pattern which was unnecessary

Comment: If you're going to include ES6 Sets, why not also ES6 classes since that would encapsulate your code just as well as your namespace pattern did. Now it just looks weird lol.

Comment: @AR7 I'm in the middle of learning ES6. not a fan of ES6 classes yet and I can't just code one up. (Actually I've switched to typescript.)

Comment: I added one in for you. Not sure why I'm so invested in this question lol. Sorry for downvoting you. Good night!

Comment: feel free to let me know if there's some problem with this, not sure what the downvotes are for