# remove object from array if property value match

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have array of objects that look like:

```
{
  "brandid": id,
  "brand": string,
  "id": id,
  "categoryId": id,
  "category": string,
  "factory": string,
  "series": string,
  "status": 0,
  "subStatus": 1
}
```

if the series property value matches another series property value in the other objects in the array, that object needs to be removed from the array.

Currently I have attempted to push them to a duplicate Array with :

```
      const seriesResCopy = seriesRes;
      const dupArray = []
      for (const thing of seriesResCopy) {
        for (const item of seriesRes) {
          if (thing.series === item.series) {
            dupArray.push(item);
          }
        }
      }
```

but this does not work. From examples I have seem my issue has been that I do not have a definite list of duplicate values to look for.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `push()` doesn't remove an element from an array, it just puts a reference (or copy if primitive) into the other array.

Comment: You dont actually remove anything. That can be done with `.splice`

Comment: So you want to filter out duplicates, triplicates, etc? Only keeping the first instance?

Comment: I am wanting to filter duplicates and keep the first instance.

Comment: @mplungjan "an array of objects like" is not "i have an object like". Don't change the question!

Comment: I did NOT change the question (at least not on purpose). I tried to make a [mcve] - so  @BrianStanley could have shown an array of objects instead of just one of the object without an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a Set of series to filter out duplicates:

```
const exists = new Set();
seriesRes = seriesRes.filter(({series}) => !exists.has(series) && exists.add(series));
```

This uses: `Array.prototype.filter`, Object destructuring and some logical tricks.

The same can be done by mutating the array:

```
const exists = new Set();
for(const [index, {series}] of seriesRes.entries()) {
  if(!exists.has(series) {
    exists.add(series);
  } else {
    seriesRes.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do explode the code and comment what it does. It is very elegant but very new (as of June 2018) too

Comment: fantastic idea with set, i have used it [lately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40482611/1447675), or later or so.

Comment: @mplungjan if you change the question, why should the answers still fit?!?

Comment: @mplungjan the OP has accepted this answer. So if you say "this does not work for my weird snippet i made out of the OPs code" then this is a fault on your side, not my's.

Comment: Your code is interesting. So how does the object need to look like to work with your code? Ops original object was not complete or valid and I just tried to male a [mcve] out of it. Why do hostile?

Comment: It would not be the first time an asker posted an object and called it an array. So all I had to do was to wrap in []. That would have been useful if OP had shown a valid array in my opinion. So not so weird. Anyway your code is still interesting

Answer (score 0):

To filter duplicates from the array and keep the first instance:

```
let seriesWithoutDuplicates = seriesRes.filter((s, i, self) => {
    return self.findIndex(z => z.series === s.series) === i;
});
```