# Removing Duplicates in Array of Objects based on Property Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have an array of objects I am trying to find duplicates based on some properties (first and last). My logic appears to be off and here is what I have tried.

My final result should look similar to:

```
[
  {first:"John", last: "Smith", id:"1234", dupes: [555,666]},
  {first:"John", last: "Jones", id:"333", dupes: []}
];
```

```js
let arrayOfObjects = 
[
  {first:"John", last: "Smith", id:"1234", dupes: []},
  {first:"John", last: "Smith", id:"555", dupes: []},
  {first:"John", last: "Jones", id:"333", dupes: []},
  {first:"John", last: "Smith", id:"666", dupes: []}
];


arrayOfObjects.forEach(record => {
  arrayOfObjects.forEach(rec => {
  if(record.first == rec.first &&
      record.last == rec.last &&
      record.id !== rec.id){
        console.log("match found for: " + JSON.stringify(record) + " and: " + JSON.stringify(rec));
        
        record.dupes.push(rec.id);
        //probably need to remove something here
      }
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects));
```

Comment: Please don't use `.map` for simple iteration. Use it when you want to transform the array into another array. If you need to just go through the values, then use `.forEach()` or a normal loop.

Comment: You should find inspiration from [How to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array of objects, and output only unique values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39885893/215552)

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ i have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, please [don't use `.map()` when not performing a mapping operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903693/is-performing-a-mapping-operation-without-using-returned-value-an-antipattern/56904505#56904505). I've substituted the usage of `.map` with `.forEach` as the latter is more appropriate in this case.

Second, your comment `//probably need to remove something here` is correct - you do have to remove an item. Namely, you have to remove the duplicate item `rec` that was just found. To do that, you can utilise [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) which requires the index to be removed. You can easily get the index [as the second parameter of the `.forEach()` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters)

```js
let arrayOfObjects = 
[
  {first:"John", last: "Smith", id:"1234", dupes: []},
  {first:"John", last: "Smith", id:"555", dupes: []},
  {first:"John", last: "Jones", id:"333", dupes: []},
  {first:"John", last: "Smith", id:"666", dupes: []}
];


arrayOfObjects.forEach(record => {
  arrayOfObjects.forEach((rec, index) => {
// get index ------------------^^^^^-->------------------>--------------v
  if(record.first == rec.first &&       //                              |
      record.last == rec.last &&        //                              |
      record.id !== rec.id){            //                              |
        record.dupes.push(rec.id);      //                              |
        arrayOfObjects.splice(index, 1) //<--- remove using the index --<
      }
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects));
```