# How to further index an object using jQuery using a value inside the object?

Tags: jquery, object

I am looking to separate the following object out by the question_id. Basically index where all question_id are the same within that index.

```
Array[13]
0
:
   Object
   answer:
   "Water leaking"
   appliance_id:
   16
   created_at:
   "2016-11-03 22:32:49"
   id:
   32
   question_id:
   40
   updated_at:
   "2016-11-03 22:32:49"
   __proto__:

Object
1
:
Object
answer:
"Front Loading"
appliance_id:
16
created_at:
"2016-11-03 22:33:16"
id:
33
question_id:
41
updated_at:
"2016-11-03 22:33:16"
__proto__:

Object
2
:
Object
answer:
"Yes"
appliance_id:
16
created_at:
"2016-11-03 22:33:23"
id:
34
question_id:
42
updated_at:
"2016-11-03 22:33:23"
__proto__:

Object
3
:
Object
answer:
"No"
appliance_id:
16
created_at:
"2016-11-03 22:33:30"
id:
35
question_id:
42
updated_at:
"2016-11-03 22:33:30"
__proto__:
Object
```

How would be the best way to separate them out into a separated object?

**UPDATE JSON**

```
        [
{"id":32,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":40,"answer":"Water leaking","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:32:49","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:32:49"},

    {"id":33,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":41,"answer":"Front Loading","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:16","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:16"},

    {"id":34,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":42,"answer":"Yes","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:23","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:23"},

    {"id":35,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":42,"answer":"No","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:30","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:30"},

    {"id":36,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":43,"answer":"Yes","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:38","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:38"},

    {"id":37,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":43,"answer":"No","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:44","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:44"},

    {"id":38,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":44,"answer":"Yes","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:53","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:53"},

    {"id":39,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":44,"answer":"No","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:02","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:02"},

    {"id":40,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":45,"answer":"Just happened","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:16","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:16"},

    {"id":41,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":46,"answer":"1-3 years ago","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:30","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:30"},

    {"id":42,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":47,"answer":"Yes","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:35","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:35"},

    {"id":43,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":47,"answer":"No","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:39","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:39"},

    {"id":44,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":46,"answer":"3-5 years ago","created_at":"2016-11-03 23:20:25","updated_at":"2016-11-03 23:20:25"}
]
```

**FULL CODE**

```
                    .done(function(response){

                      var questions = response.questions;
                      var answers = response.answers;
                      console.log(response.questions);
                      console.log(response.answers);
                      JSON.stringify(answers);

                      var question = $.map(response.questions, function (item) {
                         return item.question;
                      });

                      var question_id = $.map(response.questions, function (item) {
                         return item.id;
                      });

                      console.log(question);
                      console.log(question_id);

                      var q_id = 40;

                    //  console.log(question);

                      var n = $( question ).length;

                      var list = [];
                      for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                          list.push(i);
                      }



                      swal.setDefaults({
                        input: 'radio',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        animation: false,
                        progressSteps: list
                      })

                    // Get range of question indexes
                      var i = 0;
                      var hi = n - 1;

                      console.log(i);
                      console.log(hi);

                      // Sweet alert- Answers radio button
                      // inputOptions can be an object or Promise
                      var inputOptions = new Promise(function (resolve) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                          resolve({
                            // ANSWERS TO GO IN HERE BY QUESTION
                          })
                        }, 1000)
                      })

                      var step = [
                        {
                      title: '',
                      input: 'radio',
                      inputOptions: inputOptions,

                        },
                      ]

                     var steps = question.map((title) => {
                          var clone = Object.assign({}, step);
                          clone.title = title;
                          return clone;
                      });

                      console.log(steps);

                      swal.queue(steps).then(function (result) {
                        swal.resetDefaults()
                        swal({
                          title: 'All done!',
                          html:
                            'Your answers: <pre>' +
                              JSON.stringify(result) +
                            '</pre>',
                          confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!',
                          showCancelButton: false
                        })
                      }, function () {
                        swal.resetDefaults()
                      })
```

**Initial response to answer**

[image]

Comment: easiest to loop through with jquery `each` and grab the one that matches.

Comment: I would then need to recreate the object with the correct indexing?

Comment: Oof, please show the results of `JSON.stringify(array)` instead of copying and pasting out of the console window. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/q/30735465/215552

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have updated the question with JSON. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you read the question and answers I linked to? That should be basically what you want, as far as I can tell. You might want to include what you want the results to look like, and what you've tried.

Comment: Can you use external libs like underscore or you wanted to do it with js/jQuery? another question is do you want to have them grouped by question_id? @JamesParsons

Comment: I did have a look but was struggling to see how to rebuild the object.@MikeMcCaughan. I have something to play around with now though. Let me look into it.

Ideally all with jQuery @YaserAdelMehraban. Yes essentailly grouped by question_id. This object will then be mapped into modals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group them by question_id you can use below code:

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(groupByField) {
    var groups = {};
    this.forEach(function(el) {
        var key = el[groupByField];
        if (key in groups == false) {
            groups[key] = [];
        }
        groups[key].push(el);
    });
    return Object.keys(groups).map(function(key) {
        return {
            key: key,
            values: groups[key]
        };
    });
};
```

And the usage:

```
var newList = list.groupBy('question_id');
```

Here is the underscore equivalent:

```
var newList _.groupBy( list , 'question_id');
```

UPDATE:

Once you grouped them by question_id then after your `var q_id = 40;`:

```
var itemsWithSameQuestion = newList.filter(function(v) {
     return v.key == q_id; // Filter out the appropriate one
})
```

UPDATE 2:

Had to change `el.groupByField` to `el[groupByField]` and at last change the `v.id` in the filter to `v.key`.

See the plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/h3ZbFDNkt6J7VJjbhRNz?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Yaser... Just trying to gain some understanding of this. JS isnt my strongest language. If the original object was saved as a variable of answers. Where would that variable sit in your supplied answer.

Comment: can you update your question with a bit of your code that contains those? @JamesParsons

Comment: Thank you Yaser. I have updated the above with full code. As you can see I am using chaining modals and swift alert. So far I have mapped in the title (question). The whole process is a .done response from an AJAX query. I am pulling in all the answers. What I need to do now I group them into the answers from the specific questions and display them.

Comment: check the update, all you need to do is filter the grouped list by that id @JamesParsons

Comment: Great thanks. I am currently getting the following error though. customer_enquiry.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: keyFunction is not a function(…)

Comment: Sorry for that, updated the answer, replace the keyFunction with el.groupByField

Comment: It doesn't seem to be grouping still. I have attached an image of the result above.

Comment: I created a plunker for you and updated to match the working version @JamesParsons