# In Jquery, How to check empty and duplicate value in Json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var data = {
  "obj":[{
    "name": "John",
    "age": "10",
    "Alias": "Person",
    "where":[{"City1":"foo", "City2":"foo2"}]
  },{
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": "",
    "Alias": "Person",
    "where":[{"City1":"test1", "City2":"test2"}]
  }]
}
```

`data.obj[0].Alias` and `data.obj[1].Alias` is duplicate.

Also `data.obj[1].age` is empty.

if empty or duplicate value exists in JSON object, return false.

How can i check empty and duplicate value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values  - this post may gonna help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use filter

1. It will first check for empty age.
2. If any empty age, it will send false alert. If it sends false alert, that item will not be in the `final`.
3. Else it will try to check for duplicate `Alias`. If any item exists in the temp list that's mean it's already passed once. it will return `false`.
4. If no item exists in the temp list, it will push that item in the temp and return `true`.
5. if the total item in the `final` is not same equal to the `data` that's mean there is a invalid item in the in the json.

Like this

```
var data = {
  "obj": [{
    "name": "John",
    "age": "10",
    "Alias": "Person",
    "where": [{
      "City1": "foo",
      "City2": "foo2"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": "",
    "Alias": "Person",
    "where": [{
      "City1": "test1",
      "City2": "test2"
    }]
  }]
}

var temp = []
var final = data.obj.filter((x, y) => {
  console.log(x)
  if (x.age.length == 0) {
    return false
  } else {
    if (temp.indexOf(x.Alias) > -1){
      return false
    }
    else {
       temp.push(x.Alias)
       return true
    }
  }
})

console.log(final.length == data.obj.length ? "Valid" : "Not valid JSON")
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/5jh7986r/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: i update data.obj[1].age : "11" and data.obj[1].Alias : "Person2".
But it still return "not valid Json"...