# JS Array: tagging duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of objects like this ...

```
[{
    "Event_code": "AB-001",
    "Interest_area": "Arts",
    "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
    "End_time": "3:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-002",
    "Interest_area": "Arts",
    "Start_time": "12:30 PM",
    "End_time": "1:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-003",
    "Interest_area": "",
    "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
    "End_time": "3:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-004",
    "Interest_area": "Business",
    "Start_time": "10:30 AM",
    "End_time": "11:00 AM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-005",
    "Interest_area": "General Interest",
    "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
    "End_time": "1:30 PM",
    "Session_type": "Experience"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-006",
    "Interest_area": "Environment ,    Business       ",
    "Start_time": "11:00 AM",
    "End_time": "11:30 AM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}]
```

I am looking to implement a filter for 'Start_time' clash. My expected output should contain an extra key value pair something like "clash": "Yes". So the expected output should be ..

```
[{
    "Event_code": "AB-001",
    "Interest_area": "Arts",
    "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
    "End_time": "3:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-002",
    "Interest_area": "Arts",
    "Start_time": "12:30 PM",
    "End_time": "1:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-003",
    "Interest_area": "",
    "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
    "End_time": "3:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session",
     "clash": "yes" // Newly added key/value
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-004",
    "Interest_area": "Business",
    "Start_time": "10:30 AM",
    "End_time": "11:00 AM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-005",
    "Interest_area": "General Interest",
    "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
    "End_time": "1:30 PM",
    "Session_type": "Experience",
     "clash": "yes" // Newly added key/value
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-006",
    "Interest_area": "Environment ,    Business       ",
    "Start_time": "11:00 AM",
    "End_time": "11:30 AM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}]
```

Notice the extra "key/value" pair appears on the 1st clash (9:00 AM) onwards, not on the initial occurrence. I have seen a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465) but this doesn't tag duplicates, it rather removes them.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made an attempt to write any code to accomplish this yourself yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Using **if/else**

```js
var arr = [{"Event_code":"AB-001","Interest_area":"Arts","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-002","Interest_area":"Arts","Start_time":"12:30 PM","End_time":"1:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-003","Interest_area":"","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-004","Interest_area":"Business","Start_time":"10:30 AM","End_time":"11:00 AM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-005","Interest_area":"General Interest","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"1:30 PM","Session_type":"Experience"},{"Event_code":"AB-006","Interest_area":"Environment ,    Business       ","Start_time":"11:00 AM","End_time":"11:30 AM","Session_type":"Course information session"}];

var st = {};
arr.forEach(o => {
  if(st[o.Start_time]) o.clash = "yes";
  else st[o.Start_time] = o.Start_time;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Using **Ternary Operator**

```js
var arr = [{"Event_code":"AB-001","Interest_area":"Arts","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-002","Interest_area":"Arts","Start_time":"12:30 PM","End_time":"1:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-003","Interest_area":"","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-004","Interest_area":"Business","Start_time":"10:30 AM","End_time":"11:00 AM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-005","Interest_area":"General Interest","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"1:30 PM","Session_type":"Experience"},{"Event_code":"AB-006","Interest_area":"Environment ,    Business       ","Start_time":"11:00 AM","End_time":"11:30 AM","Session_type":"Course information session"}];

var st = {};
arr.forEach(o => st[o.Start_time] ? o.clash = "yes": st[o.Start_time] = o.Start_time);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Perfect...  Thanks @NikhilAggarwal

Comment: @Slyper - Glad to help you!

Comment: I think it's more appropriate to use `if` and `else` than the ternary operator - the ternary operator is when you need an expression (something that evaluates to a value)

Comment: @CertainPerformance - True. However, this is also a use case. Said that, your suggestion is also a valid solution. Thanks I will add this as well in the answer.