# Modifying JS Array based on some conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var arr = [{"Event_code":"AB-001","Interest_area":"Arts","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-002","Interest_area":"Arts","Start_time":"12:30 PM","End_time":"1:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-003","Interest_area":"","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-004","Interest_area":"Business","Start_time":"10:30 AM","End_time":"11:00 AM","Session_type":"Course information session"},{"Event_code":"AB-005","Interest_area":"General Interest","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"1:30 PM","Session_type":"Experience"},{"Event_code":"AB-006","Interest_area":"Environment ,    Business       ","Start_time":"11:00 AM","End_time":"11:30 AM","Session_type":"Course information session"}];
var st = {};
arr.forEach(o => {
  if(st[o.Start_time]) o.clash = "yes";
  else st[o.Start_time] = o.Start_time;
  var diff = ( new Date("1970-1-1 " + o.End_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + o.Start_time) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    //console.log(diff); // hours
    if (diff > 5){
        o.duration = "Full day event"; 
    }
});
console.log(arr);
```

What I am trying to do is add 2 key value pairs based on 2 conditions ..

Cond 1. Add "Clash":" Yes" *if 2 events have a same start time*

Cond 2: Add "Duration:"Full Day event" *if "Start time" and "end time" have a difference of more than 5 hours.*

The above code is not printing "clash":"Yes" pair.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809411) question has helped me greatly with Condition 1. I just want to add Condition 2 now.

Comment: looks like its printing `"clash":"Yes" `

Comment: Hi @azad I have added a running code snippet ... Please see above. Thanks

Comment: in the output the 3rd object has `clash` property

Answer (score 0):

For setting `clash`, you could take an object with start time and the actual index.

If another event starts at the time, set `clash` to both of the objects.

```js
var array = [{ Event_code: "AB-001", Interest_area: "Arts", Start_time: "9:00 AM", End_time: "3:00 PM", Session_type: "Course information session" }, { Event_code: "AB-002", Interest_area: "Arts", Start_time: "12:30 PM", End_time: "1:00 PM", Session_type: "Course information session" }, { Event_code: "AB-003", Interest_area: "", Start_time: "9:00 AM", End_time: "3:00 PM", Session_type: "Course information session" }, { Event_code: "AB-004", Interest_area: "Business", Start_time: "10:30 AM", End_time: "11:00 AM", Session_type: "Course information session" }, { Event_code: "AB-005", Interest_area: "General Interest", Start_time: "9:00 AM", End_time: "1:30 PM", Session_type: "Experience" }, { Event_code: "AB-006", Interest_area: "Environment, Business", Start_time: "11:00 AM", End_time: "11:30 AM", Session_type: "Course information session" }],
    clash = Object.create(null);

array.forEach((o, i, a) => {
    var diff = (new Date("1970-1-1 " + o.End_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + o.Start_time)) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    //console.log(diff); // hours
    if (diff > 5) {
        o.duration = "Full day event";
    }

    if (o.Start_time in clash) {
        a[clash[o.Start_time]].clash = true; // set first found
        o.clash = true;                      // set actual item
        return;
    }
    clash[o.Start_time] = i;                 // save index
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed your code a bit and here is new working [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hdrsww)

Comment: And here you get a fat downvote for the help. Why? )