# Check for duplicate values in array of objects in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a requirment where i need to check for only duplicate description in array of objects. Below is the object example.

```
traveler = [
   {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
   {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 10},
   {  description: 'Adult', Amount: 75},
   {  description: 'Child', Amount: 35},
   {  description: 'Infant', Amount: 25 },
   {  description: 'Adult', Amount: 105},
];
```

In the above array traveler there are objects with duplicate description, so how to check only for  duplicate description throught out the array and display a message.

I am using reduce method,below is the code. but the control is not going inside the if loop

Am i going wrong somewhere?

```
var res = traveler.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
         var existItem = acc.find(item => item.description === obj.description);
            if(existItem){
                return this.toaster.pop('info', 'Insertion unsuccessful', 'Duplicate answer found')
            } 
           });
```

Comment: you will send alert even if there is a single duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if the array of objects have duplicate property values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values)

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
reduce(){
   let res=[];
   this.traveler.map(function(item){
     var existItem = res.find(x=>x.description==item.description);
     if(existItem)
      console.log("item already exist");
     else
      res.push(item);
   });
   console.log(res);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

remove `reduce` and use only `filter`.

```
let existItem = traveler.filter(item => item.description === obj.description);
if (existItem.length > 1) {
    return this.toaster.pop('info', 'Insertion unsuccessful', 'Duplicate answer found')
}
```

Comment: where does 'obj' came from ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code:

```
var traveler = [
  {
    description: "Senior",
    Amount: 50
  },
  {
    description: "Senior",
    Amount: 10
  },
  {
    description: "Adult",
    Amount: 75
  },
  {
    description: "Child",
    Amount: 35
  },
  {
    description: "Infant",
    Amount: 25
  },
  {
    description: "Adult",
    Amount: 105
  }
];

function hasDuplicateDesc(collection) {
  var groups = collection.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.description] = (acc[cur.description] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return Object.values(groups).some(num => num > 1);
}

if (hasDuplicateDesc(traveler)) {
  return this.toaster.pop(
    "info",
    "Insertion unsuccessful",
    "Duplicate answer found"
  );
}
```

`groups` is an object which basically creates an object:

```
{
  "Senior": 2,
  "Adult": 2,
  "Child": 1,
  "Infant": 1
}
```

We grab the values the object using `Object.values(groups)`, and check if there is a single number which is grater than `1`. If exists any `num > 1`, then we can say duplicate description is present.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i am getting a error, Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

Answer (score 1):

The control is not going inside the if block because you're not pushing anything into `acc` (and you didn't initialized it in the last argument of reduce), the reduce operation won't do it for you.

This solution should work:

```
var res = traveler.reduce((acc, obj)=> {
    var existItem = acc.find(item => item.description === obj.description);
    if(existItem) {
        return this.toaster.pop(
            'info', 'Insertion unsuccessful', 'Duplicate answer found'
        );
    }
    acc.push(obj);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

With this `res` will contain unique values and you will be notified of duplicates with your `toaster.pop`.
But you can also keep the duplicates by pushing into a duplicateList inside your if block.

Answer (score 0):

here iam trying to figure it out duplicate emails in the array.
i have **enteredEmails** array which is having the list of emails which may unique or duplicate.

please find the below example.

```
this.enteredEmails.forEach(emailItr => {

      matchedEmail = [];
      matchedEmail = this.enteredEmails.filter((val) => val.emailId === emailItr.emailId);

      if (matchedEmail.length > 1) {
        return this.isDuplicate = true;

      }

    });

}
```