# Typescript array of objects check for duplicates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have requirement where I need to check duplicates for object items.

In the below Array of object, I need to check for "empno" OR "extension" and If there are any duplicates then I need to throw an error.

I have tried this [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876175/check-for-duplicate-values-in-array-of-objects-in-angular2) but it didn't work for me.

```
[
    {
        "id": 269,
        "empno": "34567",
        "extension": 345
    },
    {
        "id": 269,
        "empno": "34568",
        "extension": 346
    },
    {
        "id": 269,
        "empno": "34569",
        "extension": 345
    },
    {
        "id": 269,
        "empno": "34567",
        "extension": 345
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to allow for efficient lookups of existing values:

```
const hasDuplicates = (data) => {
  const set = new Set();

  for (let {empno, extension} of data) {
    const key = `${empno}/${extension}`;
    if (set.has(key)) {
      return true;
    }

    set.add(key);
  }

  return false;
};
```

**Full snippet:**

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 269,
    "empno": "34567",
    "extension": 345
  },
  {
    "id": 269,
    "empno": "34568",
    "extension": 346
  },
  {
    "id": 269,
    "empno": "34569",
    "extension": 345
  },
  {
    "id": 269,
    "empno": "34567",
    "extension": 345
  }
];

const hasDuplicates = (data) => {
  const set = new Set();
  
  for (let {empno, extension} of data) {
    const key = `${empno}/${extension}`;
    if (set.has(key)) {
      return true;
    }
    
    set.add(key);
  }
  
  return false;
};

console.log(hasDuplicates(data));
```

---

If you want something less verbose at the cost of processing the entire array even if duplicates have already been found, you can reduce to a `Set` and compare its size with the original array:

```
const hasDuplicates = (data) => data.length !== data.reduce((a, {empno, extension}) => a.add(`${empno}/${extension}`), new Set).size;
```

**Full snippet:**

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 269,
    "empno": "34567",
    "extension": 345
  },
  {
    "id": 269,
    "empno": "34568",
    "extension": 346
  },
  {
    "id": 269,
    "empno": "34569",
    "extension": 345
  },
  {
    "id": 269,
    "empno": "34567",
    "extension": 345
  }
];

const hasDuplicates = (data) => data.length !== data.reduce((a, {empno, extension}) => a.add(`${empno}/${extension}`), new Set).size;

console.log(hasDuplicates(data));
```