# How can I check if the array of objects have duplicate property values with more properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, duplicates

I have searched StackOverflow and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values), but it does not solve my problem.

My problem is, my array is like this:

```js
let arr = [
  {type: 1, id: 1, name:'aa'},
  {type: 1, id: 1, name:'bb'},
  {type: 2, id: 1, name:'cc'}
]
```

And I need to find same `type` and same `id` and then recognize that this is duplicate object. Above, `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` is a duplicate but `arr[0]` and `arr[2]` are not. I have tried using ES6 methods such as `.some()`, `.every()`, and a `Set()`, but non of these have worked for me. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is your expected result? A boolean? The array with the duplicates removed?

Comment: yes，I just need Boolean result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to map each object to a string. Each string takes the shape of `type-id` for that object. Then, using a `Set` you can remove all duplicate strings. You can then check if the set size equals the array length to determine if there are any duplicates or not in the array:

```js
const containsDups = arr => new Set(arr.map(({type, id}) => `${type}-${id}`)).size !== arr.length;

const arr = [{type: 1, id: 1, name:'aa'},{type: 1, id: 1, name:'bb'},{type: 2, id: 1, name:'cc'}];
console.log(containsDups(arr));
```

Comment: Why `Set()` can not determine Object duplicates?I have try ```let set = new Set();set.add({type:1,id:1});set.add({type:1,id:1});console.log(set.size) // 2(why?)```

Comment: @yang because objects are reference types, so two objects are not the same if they’re different reference types. So {} != {} will return true. Since object equality can not be determined like this, the set also cannot determine when two objects as the same. So, you need to use a string, where equality where work

Answer (score 0):

you can use Set:

Set is a new data object introduced in ES6. Because Set only lets you store unique values

```js
const seen = new Set();

const arr = [
  {type: 1, id: 1, name:'aa'},
  {type: 1, id: 1, name:'bb'},
  {type: 2, id: 1, name:'cc'}
];

const filteredArr = arr.filter((el, index) => {
  const duplicate = seen.has(el.type, el.id);
  seen.add(el.type, el.id);
  console.log('index: '+ index +' is duplicate: '+ duplicate);
  return !duplicate;    //  if you just need a boolean, this is what you are looking for.
});

console.log('new array: ' + JSON.stringify(filteredArr));
```

Comment: The `.add` and `.has` method only accepts one value. So if the second object has the same `type` but different `id` to the first it will still be removed

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to group by properties such as `type` and `id` and then check whether `names` more than `1`. If yes, it means, that there is at least one duplicate:

```
const result = [...arr.reduce((r, o) => {
    const key = o.type + '-' + o.id;
    const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
        names: []
    });
    item.names.push(o.name);
    return r.set(key, item);
}, new Map).values()];
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [{type: 1, id: 1, name:'aa'},{type: 1, id: 1, name:'bb'},{type: 2, id: 1, name:'cc'}]

const result = [...arr.reduce((r, o) => {
    const key = o.type + '-' + o.id;
    const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
        names: []
    });
    item.names.push(o.name);
    return r.set(key, item);
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(`Is there duplicates: `, result.some(s => s.names.length > 1));
```