# find duplicate before pushing new values

Tags: javascript

I need to know the best method to check if the value is in the array before push it

I have an array :

```
coordinates: [
     {x: 160, y: 160},
     {x: 192, y: 160},
     {x: 224, y: 160},
     {x: 224, y: 192},
     ];
```

For each call of my function , I need to check if new coordinates is it before proceed to push.

```
const payload= {x: 224, y: 190}

//Next function call 

const payload = {x: 224, y: 190}   // need to refuse pushing this value
```

I tried filter and other JS methods without success.

for example:

```
coordinates.filter(c => {if(payload !== c){coordinates.push(new)});
```

This one doesn't work for me .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if the array of objects have duplicate property values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var payload = {x: 224, y: 190};
var coordinates = [
 {x: 160, y: 160},
 {x: 192, y: 160},
 {x: 224, y: 160},
 {x: 224, y: 192},
];

var filtered = coordinates.filter(c => c.x == payload.x &&
c.y == payload.y);
if (filtered.length == 0) filtered.push(payload)

console.log("Filtered:", filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

since each coordinate is an object, you'll need to do a deep comparison to check if the object exists in your array already:

```js
const coordinates = [{
  x: 160,
  y: 160
}, {
  x: 192,
  y: 160
}, {
  x: 224,
  y: 160
}, {
  x: 224,
  y: 192
}];
const isInArray = newCoordinate => coordinates.filter(c => newCoordinate.x === c.x && newCoordinate.y === c.y).length > 0;
console.log(isInArray({
  x: 0,
  y: 0
})) // false
console.log(isInArray({
  x: 160,
  y: 160
})) // true
```

Comment: if it's duplicate how can I do for delete them from array ?

Comment: you can use the `true` or `false` value returned from `isInArray` to determine whether to push the next coordinate into the array.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
var coordinates= [
     {x: 160, y: 160},
     {x: 192, y: 160},
     {x: 224, y: 160},
     {x: 224, y: 192},
     ];

const payload = {x: 225, y: 193};


for(let prop of coordinates){
 if(prop.x == payload.x || prop.y == payload.y){
  var includes = true;
 } else {
  includes = false;
 }
}

if(includes == false){
 coordinates.push(payload);
}
console.log(coordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple checker function to check duplicate objects

```js
var coordinates=[
     {x: 160, y: 160},
     {x: 192, y: 160},
     {x: 224, y: 160},
     {x: 224, y: 192},
];

const pushCoordinate=(obj)=>{
 var flag=0;
 coordinates.forEach((elem)=>{
   if(obj.x===elem.x && obj.y===elem.y){
     flag=1;
    }
  });
  if(flag===1){
   return false;
  }else{
   return true;
  }
};

var payload1 = {x: 224, y: 190};
var payload2 = {x:224, y:190};

if(pushCoordinate(payload1)){
 coordinates.push(payload1);
}

if(pushCoordinate(payload2)){
 coordinates.push(payload2);
}

console.log(coordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use filter array method to check x,y values

and if the filtered array has no length then there are no matching values and push payload object

```js
let filteredArr;
let coordinates = [
    {x: 160, y: 160},
    {x: 192, y: 160},
    {x: 224, y: 160},
    {x: 224, y: 192}
    ];
    
// checker fn
const checker = (obj) => filteredArr = coordinates.filter(elm => obj.x == elm.x && obj.y == elm.y);

let payload = {x: 224, y: 190};
checker(payload);

// no matching
if (filteredArr.length === 0) coordinates.push(payload);
console.log(coordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some()` to check whether `coordinates` array includes the values of `payload` object

```js
const coordinates = [
  {x: 160, y: 160},
  {x: 192, y: 160},
  {x: 224, y: 160},
  {x: 224, y: 192},
];

const payload = {x: 224, y: 192};

if(!coordinates.some(({x, y}) => x === payload.x && y === payload.y)) {
  coordinates.push(payload);
}

console.log(coordinates);
```