# check if array of objects contains multiple objects

Tags: javascript

I Have this array

```
var array = [ { id:1 , name:'test1'},
              { id:2 , name:'test2'},
              { id:3 , name:'test3'},
              { id:4 , name:'test4'}]
```

how to check if array contains two objects by name property test1 and test2

Comment: _"How to..."_ - A loop will do the job quite well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if the array of objects have duplicate property values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to do it:

```js
var array = [
  { id:1 , name:'test1'},
  { id:2 , name:'test2'},
  { id:3 , name:'test3'},
  { id:4 , name:'test4'}
];

const tests = ['test1', 'test2'];

const result = tests.every(test => array.some(e => e.name === test));

console.log(result);
```