# How to calcuate item quantiy from array of object if the itemid is same and how to sum up those quantity whose date are same too

Tags: javascript

I have data in this format

```
const ChkdArr = [
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 29,
    quantity: 4,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-26",
    itemId: 29,
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 7,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 4,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-27",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-28",
    itemId: 47,
    quantity: 1,
  },
];
```

i am getting trouble to get a new array with those data whose itemid is same and in those item if the date is same sum up their quantity.

I want the result to look like this i am applying map and filters but my data is repeating and having incorrect results

```
const DateSortArr = [{
    itemId: 29,
    date: [
      { date: "2022-05-25", quantity: 4 },
      { date: "2022-05-26", quantity: 2 },
    ],
},
  {
    itemId: 36,
    date: [
      { date: "2022-05-25", quantity: 11 },
      { date: "2022-05-27", quantity: 2 },
    ],},
{
    itemId: 47,
    date: [{ date: "2022-05-25", quantity: 1 }],
  },
];
```

Comment: have you tried the filter method?

Comment: yes  what i did  is apply map first and then apply filte to check itemid matches the remainig itemid and then i check the dates of that itemid but i cant seem to get what am i doing wrong.

Comment: check out this!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done efficiently using a map, and a new output array. In the map, we will store the key as itemId and value as its index in the output array. Then we will loop through the data, and see if the itemId has an index in the map, if it is we will look up that item value from output array, and update the current date value accordingly, otherwise we will create a new object for that item in the array. The below code does just that.

```
const data = [
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 29,
    quantity: 4,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-26",
    itemId: 29,
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 7,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 4,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-27",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-28",
    itemId: 47,
    quantity: 1,
  },
];

let output = [];
let itemIdToIndexMap = {};

data.forEach(item => {
    const itemIndex = itemIdToIndexMap[item.itemId];
    if(itemIndex !== undefined) {
         const itemArray = output[itemIndex];
         const itemWithCurrentDate = itemArray.date.find(newItem => item.date === newItem.date);
         if(itemWithCurrentDate) {
             itemWithCurrentDate.quantity += item.quantity; 
         } else {
             itemArray.date.push({date: item.date, quantity: item.quantity});
         }
    } else {
        output.push({itemId: item.itemId, date: [{date: item.date, quantity: item.quantity}]});
        itemIdToIndexMap[item.itemId] = output.length - 1;
    }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I don't know id undrestand you  but you use this fun :

```
function groupBy(collection, property) {
  var i = 0, val, index,
      values = [], result = [];
  for (; i < collection.length; i++) {
      val = collection[i][property];
      index = values.indexOf(val);
      if (index > -1)
          result[index].push(collection[i]);
      else {
          values.push(val);
          result.push([collection[i]]);
      }
  }
  return result;
}

const ChkdArr = [
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 29,
    quantity: 4,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-26",
    itemId: 29,
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 7,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 4,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-27",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-28",
    itemId: 47,
    quantity: 1,
  },
];
var obj = groupBy(ChkdArr, "date");

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ChkdArr = [
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 29,
    quantity: 4,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-26",
    itemId: 29,
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 7,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-25",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 4,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-27",
    itemId: 36,
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-28",
    itemId: 47,
    quantity: 1,
  },
];

let answer = [];

ChkdArr.map(item =>{
  let id = answer.findIndex(it =>it.itemId === item.itemId);
  if(id === - 1 ){
    answer.push({itemId: item.itemId, data: [{date: item.date, quantity: item.quantity}]})
  }else{
    answer [id] = {itemId: item.itemId, data: [...answer[id].data, {date: item.date, quantity: item.quantity}]}
  }
})

console.log(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to firstly group each item by `itemId`, then by `date`.

We then add the quantity to each value, finally we use Object.values() to turn our mapping objects to an array.

```js
const ChkdArr = [ { date: "2022-05-25", itemId: 29, quantity: 4, }, { date: "2022-05-26", itemId: 29, quantity: 2, }, { date: "2022-05-25", itemId: 36, quantity: 7, }, { date: "2022-05-25", itemId: 36, quantity: 4, }, { date: "2022-05-27", itemId: 36, quantity: 2, }, { date: "2022-05-28", itemId: 47, quantity: 1, }, ];

const result = Object.values((ChkdArr.reduce((acc, { date, itemId, quantity }) => { 
    acc[itemId] = acc[itemId] || { itemId, date: [] };
    let index = (acc[itemId]['date'].findIndex(v => v.date === date));
    // If we find an entry for date, add the quantity otherwise create a new object.
    if (index === -1) {
       (acc[itemId]['date']).push({ date, quantity })
    } else { 
        acc[itemId]['date'][index].quantity += quantity;
    }
    return acc;
}, {})))

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```