# ES6 - How to check if Multiple properties in an array of objects have duplicate values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Following is a sample array that I have. The goal is to determine whether there are duplicate entries based on a **number of fields** (details below) -

```
values = [
    {
        "name": "123",
        "loginTime": "01:00:00",
        "logoutTime": "01:00:00",
        "description": "test",
        "message": "test2",
        "status": "test3"
    },
    {
        "name": "123",
        "loginTime": "01:00:00",
        "logoutTime": "00:00:00",
        "description": "test",
        "message": "test2",
        "status": "test3"
    },
    {
        "name": "222",
        "loginTime": "01:00:00",
        "logoutTime": "00:00:00",
        "description": "test2",
        "message": "test2",
        "status": "test1"
    }
]
```

I am aware of the similar looking popular question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values), however, the scenario I'm talking about is different. In that question, the user is concerned mainly about the `name` field only and so the `Set` based solution works fine. In my case, however, I need to determine the existence of duplicate data if the `name, description, message, status` fields are the same between any two entries in `values` (and so not just one field). So from the example list above, the first two entries are duplicates, since all the mentioned fields have the same value between them. At least one of the aforementioned fields will need to have a non-duplicate value here. What would be an ES6 compliant way to detect the duplicate data here?

A `Set` based solution makes sense for when there's just one field that we'll have to look into to determine the duplication. Not sure how one would do it for multiple fields.

Comment: I guess you'd have to use a reduce and check for each item if a duplicate exists in the source array, comparing the fields you need to compare.

Comment: could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: Are you trying to detect duplicate data or just remove it?

Comment: @Feathercrown just detect. No removal necessary here. There can be tens of entries in this array, and the moment any two entries have the same value for name, description, message and status fields, it'll need to return true, for example.

Comment: As @Peterrabbit mentioned, you can use reduce to check for duplicates. [Here's an example](https://playcode.io/989992)

Comment: @K.L. thanks for the example. My goal here is to actually detect whether there is a duplication between any two entries. Given that, what would be the necessary changes to this reduce function so that it returns a boolean if there's a duplicate found? I tried by returning true if foundDuplicate is truthy, that didn't work though. Apologies if it's direct, I'm not super familiar with the intricacies of the reduce method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the key fields into a single value and then use that in a Set. For creating the combined value you may use `JSON.stringify` on an array of fields:

```js
const hasDuplicates = values =>
    new Set(
        values.map(({name, description, message, status}) =>
            JSON.stringify([name, description, message, status]))
    ).size < values.length;

const values = [{"name": "123","loginTime": "01:00:00","logoutTime": "01:00:00","description": "test","message": "test2","status": "test3"},{"name": "123","loginTime": "01:00:00","logoutTime": "00:00:00","description": "test","message": "test2","status": "test3"},{"name": "222","loginTime": "01:00:00","logoutTime": "00:00:00","description": "test2","message": "test2","status": "test1"}];

console.log(hasDuplicates(values))
```

Comment: makes perfect sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement over the other answer, to avoid repeating property names:

```js
const keys = ['name', 'description', 'message', 'status'];
const hasDuplicates = values => 
    new Set(values.map(v => JSON.stringify(keys.map(key => v[key]))))
    .size < values.length;

const values = [{"name": "123","loginTime": "01:00:00","logoutTime": "01:00:00","description": "test","message": "test2","status": "test3"},{"name": "123","loginTime": "01:00:00","logoutTime": "00:00:00","description": "test","message": "test2","status": "test3"},{"name": "222","loginTime": "01:00:00","logoutTime": "00:00:00","description": "test2","message": "test2","status": "test1"}];
console.log(hasDuplicates(values));
```

Comment: this is a really nice improvement over the other answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(values) {
    const tempArr = values.map(item => { 
    return { 
        name: item.name, 
        description: item.description, 
        message: item.message, 
        status: item.status 
    } 
});
   let ignoreIndex = [];
   const indexToSplice = tempArr.map(JSON.stringify).map((item, index) => tempArr.findIndex((obj, i) => {
   if(JSON.stringify(obj) === item && i !== index && !ignoreIndex.includes(index)) {
        ignoreIndex.push(i);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
})).filter(number => number >= 0 ? true : false);
indexToSplice.forEach(index => values.splice(index, 1));
return values;
}

const values = [
    {
        "name": "123",
        "loginTime": "01:00:00",
        "logoutTime": "01:00:00",
        "description": "test",
        "message": "test2",
        "status": "test3"
    },
    {
        "name": "123",
        "loginTime": "01:00:00",
        "logoutTime": "00:00:00",
        "description": "test",
        "message": "test2",
        "status": "test3"
    },
    {
        "name": "222",
        "loginTime": "01:00:00",
        "logoutTime": "00:00:00",
        "description": "test2",
        "message": "test2",
        "status": "test1"
    }
]

console.log(test(values))
```