# check if duplicates exist in array object

Tags: angular, typescript, arrayobject

I want to reaturn true/false if there is some duplicates on object array.

```
arr = [
     { nr:10, name: 'aba' },
     { nr:11, name: 'cba' },
     { nr:10, name: 'aba' }
]

 arr2 = [
         { year:2020, city: 'Aaa' },
         { year:2010, city: 'Bbb' },
         { year:2020, city: 'Aaa' }
    ]
```

I found many solutions for one value but what if we want to check the whole object. Do I have to do foreach?

```
 const result: T[] = [];
    for (const item of array) {
        if (!result.includes(item)) {
            result.push(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if the array of objects have duplicate property values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values)

Comment: @YongShun I tried to use the method from these answers to compare more than one value (year, city), but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JSON.stringify and `map` and `some` array methods.

```
let arr = [
     { nr:10, name: 'aba' },
     { nr:11, name: 'cba' },
     { nr:10, name: 'aba' }

]


 let valuesStringify = arr2.map(x => JSON.stringify(x));

 let duplicate = valuesStringify.some((item, i) => valuesStringify.indexOf(item) !== i)

console.log(duplicate) //true
```

[enter link description here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjEF4IG0BQEMYN4QHYwC4BGABgBo8oBbEAiAcigCMp6IBfM9TCHfYohVzVaDAMYs2nbpj6FSQkXUaSOEVKgC6GiKEgA3KMACuIAM4BlMDACWuAOY2AZgE9E0OADoqUAA4AKAA9EAD4IACkLAHkAOU8zaztHVyCASlSAbnQ9CAATY19gGzEoMBB3QxNzK1sHZxd4gHsaf38bMqoKG1TQiErTS0S61087XJBAqKc2jp6AQgQkbo0xRtwzRtBPYEb7f3zC4tKQVNQgA)

Answer (score 1):

Using combo of `Array.prototype.some`, `Array.prototype.every` and `Object.entries`

This checks each item of array against the rest of the array (`slice(index + 1)`) to see if some object is equal.

```js
function hasDuplicates(arr) {
  // check each item of array against rest of the array
  return arr.some((obj, index) => arr.slice(index + 1).some(obj2 => {
    // check obj is equal obj2
    return Object.entries(obj).every(([key, value]) => obj2[key] === value)
  }))
}

let arr = [
  { nr:10, name: 'aba' },
  { nr:11, name: 'cba' },
  { nr:10, name: 'aba' }
];

let arr2 = [
  { year:2020, city: 'Aaa' },
  { year:2010, city: 'Bbb' },
  { year:2020, city: 'Ccc' }
];

console.log(hasDuplicates(arr)); // true
console.log(hasDuplicates(arr2)); // false
```